# Android Studio says there isnt google play services

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an android project and until today it was fine. It gets user data and creates a connection via websocket to server. I started the project to check something and it worked normally and 2 minutes later I started t again it stopped getting user location and it said there is a problem with google play sevices

W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.zap is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: com.example.airboxproject requires the Google Play Store, but it is missing.
W/GoogleApiManager: The service for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.service.zap is not available: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SERVICE_INVALID, resolution=null, message=null}

I wouldn't get this messages before but now it keeps producing these error and I don't know what to do. I deleted the emulator and uploaded a new one and now there is difference in it GUI. I have to submit this project in less than 48 hours and I'm having problems with it.

Edit: It shows some parts of the GUI as Android 2 even though it is Android 11

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Create a new emulator from Android Studio and verify it has Google Play Installed. Tools > Device Manager > Create Device. Select a device which has the Google Play logo under the Play Store column.

And/or verify the correct emulator is selected next to the run button at the top of Android studio.

It is also best practice to check if the device supports Google Play Services.

Uncomment if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) conditional for an automatic dialog to the user explaining the error

```
 public static boolean isPlayServicesInstalled(Context context) {
    GoogleApiAvailabilityLight googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailabilityLight.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context);
    //This call shows a dialog not controlled by the app (dialog text controlled by Firebase package)
    // so do not show this as if self handled
    //            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
    //                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Google Play Services are not installed");
    //                GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    //                Objects.requireNonNull(googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(frag, result, 6)).show();
    //            }
    return result == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS;
}
```

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GoogleApiAvailability

Comment: I've done this as you've told. first it started working like it used to. But now it started to give same errors again.

Comment: See updated answer which shows a check for google play services.  My best guess is emulator device changed or another exception is being thrown

Comment: When emulator has started it wait a moment and says "Error while waiting for device: Illegal char <*> at index 0: *.lock" I can't find any solution for this.

Comment: I deleted Android Studio completely (Not just deleting it from control panel) and I downloaded it again. It downloaded the SDK again so it works for now.